# Apple Mach-O Linker Error (Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i have error like this :

```
Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pams_v-1.1-cmybounmouobwianhdnootdokdam/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PAMS.app/PAMS normal x86_64
cd "/Users/user/Desktop/iOS Maul Testing/Pams v-1.1"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pams_v-1.1-cmybounmouobwianhdnootdokdam/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pams_v-1.1-cmybounmouobwianhdnootdokdam/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pams_v-1.1-cmybounmouobwianhdnootdokdam/Build/Intermediates/Pams\ v-1.1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pams\ v-1.1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PAMS.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pams_v-1.1-cmybounmouobwianhdnootdokdam/Build/Intermediates/Pams\ v-1.1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pams\ v-1.1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PAMS.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -framework Foundation -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreFoundation -framework Security -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pams_v-1.1-cmybounmouobwianhdnootdokdam/Build/Intermediates/Pams\ v-1.1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pams\ v-1.1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PAMS_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pams_v-1.1-cmybounmouobwianhdnootdokdam/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PAMS.app/PAMS

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_main", referenced from:
 implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i try to delete DrivedData Folder and clear build but its still error...

Answer (score 0):

Try one thing :

Go to **Project -> Build Phases -> Compiled Sources** and Make sure main.m is present there .

Comment: all of my swift file in there... but its still error